# set MenuItem unclickable in SystemTray

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenuitem, jpopup

I want to set my Menuitem in Java unclickable. It should be shown, but not clickable and there shouldn't be a hover color, when you go with your mouse over it.
In other words, I want to show a text for info in System-Tray menu. It has no onclick function.
The System Tray and the showing works completly, I only need help for this problem above.

```
 MenuItem itmPrgName = new MenuItem(Main.programmName + " " + Main.version);
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to set my Menuitem in Java unclickable. It should be shown, but
>   not clickable and there shouldn't be a hover color, when you go with
>   your mouse over it. In other words, I want to show a text for info in
>   System-Tray menu. It has no onclick function.

- use `JPopup` as container put there `JLabel` / `JTextArea(setEditable(false))` / `JTextPane (setEditable(false))` or `JPanel` contains different amount of `JComponents`
- set proper `LayoutManager` for JPopup or JPanel if needed

Comment: I want to do this in the System Tray. Is Jpopup possible there?!

Comment: yes there is only (directly implemented in API) JPopup or show message

Comment: JPopupMenu x = new JPopupMenu();
x.add(new JLabel("hallo"));
trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "description", x);

Comment: I don't understand how to implement it in the Tray. Can you give me an example?;)